# javascript for loop inside for loop calculation

Tags: javascript, for-loop

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zdjocaLu/)**

```
function myFunction() {
  diff = 4;
  var l = 12;

  b = document.getElementById("yee").value;

  var a = Number(document.getElementById("base").value);
  var aa = (a*b)/100;
  z = aa;
  var r = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
    if(i) {
      var hk = (aa * document.getElementById("per").value) / 100;
      aa+= Number(hk);
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
      var d = ((z*j)*5)/12/100;
      r += j+1 +") " + aa.toFixed(2) + "---" + d.toFixed(2) + "<br/>";
    }

    r += "";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += r;
}
```

Here, I am trying to calculate base percent (12) from base quantity (10000) for first 12 months. Final output for 12 month is 1200.

After 12 counts (months) whole percent (10) will be added to base quantity (10000) and then next 12 months, calculate base percent (12) from previous base quantity (11000). Final output for second 12 month is 1320.

After 12 counts (months) whole percent (10) will be added to previous base quantity (11000) and then next 12 months, calculate base percent (12)  from previous base quantity (12100). Final output for third 12 month is 1452.

Tried so far,

[image]

Result I am expecting,

[image]

Finally, I got the result for 2nd column as I am expected. But, I didn't get the 1st and 3rd column result as I am expected. I want to calculate this formula (((z*j) * 5)/12/100) for l * diff that means 12*4 for 48 counts. But, it resets every 12 counts. How do I calculate the first & third column continuously?

Comment: checkout my fiddle and tell is there any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initiaze another variable k because every time the loop runs it start from 0 and you are using j.

```js
function myFunction() {
  diff = 4;
  var l = 12;

  b = document.getElementById("yee").value;

  var a = Number(document.getElementById("base").value);
  var aa = (a * b) / 100;
  z = aa;
  var r = "";
  k = 0;
  m = 0;
  e = 0;
  z = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
    if (i) {
      var hk = (aa * document.getElementById("per").value) / 100;
      aa += Number(hk);

    }
    n = m;

    for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) {

      var d = ((aa * n) * 5) / 12 / 100;
      var f  = d+z;

      r += k + 1 + ") " + aa.toFixed(2) + "---" + f.toFixed(2) + "<br/>";
      k++;
      n++;
    }
    r += "";
    m++;
    z = z + d;

  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += r;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Base Quantity</span>
  <input type="text" id="base" value="10000" />
</div>
<div>
  <span>Base Percent</span>
  <input type="text" id="yee" value="12" />
</div>
<div>
  <span>Whole Percent</span>
  <input type="text" id="per" value="10" />
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: @KaruppiahRK k should be initialize outside both loops

Answer (score 1):

```
        function myFunction() {
        let diff = 4;
        let l = 12;
        let basePercent = document.getElementById("yee").value;                
        let baseQuantity = Number(document.getElementById("base").value);
        let wholePercent = document.getElementById("per").value;
        let aa = (baseQuantity * basePercent) / 100;
        let d = 0;
        let z = 0;
        let r = "";
        let monthCounter = 1;

        for (let i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
            if(i) {
                let hk = (aa * wholePercent) / 100;
                aa += Number(hk);
            }

            /*d is a constant value you keep adding every month. you need to calculate it in the outer loop and
            add it to it self in every iteration of inner loop*/
            if( i === 0) {
                d = ((aa)*5)/12/100;
            } else {
                d = ((aa*i)*5)/12/100;
            }

            for (let j = 0; j < l; j++) {
                if(i ===0 && j === 0){
                    z = 0;
                } else {
                    z += d;
                }
                r += monthCounter +") " + aa.toFixed(2) + "---" + z.toFixed(2) + "<br/>";
                ++monthCounter;
            }
            r += "";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += r;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create variables to store num of loops completed. One will set first col and second will handle the third column. Update both variables at end of inner loop.

```
for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
  var d = (((z*j)*5)/12/100) + offset;
  r += (j+1 + (offset2*l)) +") " + aa.toFixed(2) + "---" + d.toFixed(2) + "<br/>";
}
offset2++;
offset += (((z*(j-1))*5)/12/100) + (((z*(0))*5)/12/100) + 0.5
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maheerali121/jf712c0h/19/)

Comment: I think there is something wrong in this calculation method. 12th and 13th rows shows 55 & 55.50. That is wrong.